# Extending vim Fortran Syntax file for pFUnit testing framework

Tags: vim, syntax, fortran, xunit

I want to use the **pFUnit** Fortran Unit Testing Framework with **vim**. The tests are usually written in a file with the ending `.pf`, and they use mostly Fortran 95 syntax, except that they have unittesting specific keywords (like `@test` and `@assertEqual`)

What is the easiest way to extend the fortran syntax highlighting in **vim** to also mark these special words only in files with the `.pf` extension?

Thanks

Example Unit Test:

```
@test
subroutine test_to_lower_all_A()
    use pfunit_mod
    use mod_str_tools, only: to_lower
    @assertEqual("aaa", to_lower("AAA"))
end subroutine
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here's what I did which seems to solve the issue:

1) Create a file in `~/.vim/ftdetect/pFUnit.vim`

```
" ftdetect/pFUnit.vim
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.pf setfiletype pFUnit
```

This automatically sets the file type according to the file extension

2) Create a file in `~/.vim/ftplugin/pFUnit.vim`

```
" ftplugin/pFUnit.vim
setlocal iskeyword+=@-@
let fortran_free_form=1
so $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/fortran.vim
```

This says that the `@` character is part of a keyword, not a separator.
It also sets the `fortran_free_form` tag and loads the fortran plugin.

3) Create a file in `~/.vim/syntax/pFUnit.vim`

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: pFUnit

if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

syn keyword pFUnitTag @test @before @after @suite
syn keyword pFUnitAssert @assertTrue @assertFalse @assertAny @assertAll @assertNone @assertNotAll
syn keyword pFUnitAssert @assertEqual @assertLessThan @assertLessThanOrEqual @assertGreaterThan @assertGreaterThanOrEqual
syn keyword pFUnitAssert @assertRelativelyEqual
syn keyword pFUnitAssert @assertIsNaN @assertIsFinite @assertExceptionRaised @assertSameShape

hi def link pFUnitTag PreProc
hi def link pFUnitAssert Keyword

so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/fortran.vim

let b:current_syntax = "pFUnit"
```

This now both defines the new keywords, and sources the original `fortran.vim`. It is important to source that file before setting `b:current_syntax`, because otherwise the `fortran.vim` script exits immediately.

If anyone has a better solution, feel free to share here. Thanks